# Google slides blurs pixel art

Tags: google-slides

When I put a pixel art png image into google slides, it gets blurred. The pixels get interpolated. Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications](/tour "Web Apps Tour"). Consider [registering your account](/users/login "Login") to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. [Registering](/users/login "Login") is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/)

Comment: Without a sample of the image and/or slide we can't help you. Note that PNG images have a fixed resolution and will look bad if displayed at a smaller or larger resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible for end-users of Google Slides. The Google Slices official help articles need to mention how to do this.

What you see on the screen depends on multiple factors. Particularly, Google Slides optimizes the uploaded image for sending the image from the Google data centers to the user's computer, considering that the image will be displayed on a web browser.

A possible workaround might be "to hack" how your web browser works by configuring your computer to use custom code snippets instead of code downloaded from Google servers. This code snippet should take the images from another source than the image uploaded directly to Google Slides, like Google Drive or, better, a location on your computer.

This might be an overkill solution compared to using an installable presentation app, such as Microsoft PowerPoint, Apple Keynotes, or LibreOffice Impress.

On the other hand, the problem might be related to your computer hardware and software, specifically how the display works.